# International vehicle registration sticker

Tags: legal, europe, driving, road-trips

I will drive my car, registered in the Canadian province Alberta, in Europe. Do I need the country (CDN) sticker on the car? My licence plate shows Alberta, but not Canada. I have no idea where to buy such sticker.

Comment: Are you emigrating to Europe?

Comment: Yes, I am moving to Prague.

Comment: What are you using for insurance in Europe?  Alberta insurance is only valid in Canada, the 50 US states plus the District of Columbia.

Comment: Make sure you check all the requirements for importing that car. You will need to register the car locally, probably go through homologation (which may require changes to the car), possibly pay taxes...

Comment: I am planning to register the car in CZ. I need to go through technical & homologation process, but as long as the car is less than 8 years old there is no problem. The only difference I can see is that the rear blinkers are red, not orange. But apparently you can apply for exemption. Before the registration is complete I can use the car on the road, provided I get a local insurance (based on car VIN code).

Comment: I believe this question was closed incorrectly. Although it's true that OP is emigrating to europe, the scope of the question is strictly limited to whether or not a Canadian vehicle requires a CDN bumper sticker to drive in Europe.

Comment: @zeocrash In principle, I agree. However, in practice, it's such a hassle to bring a car from Canada to Europe (even just physically moving the thing) that only somebody who's emigrating would try.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've seen rally drivers ship their cars around. I've also seen travellers taking their car on a one-way roadtrip and shipping their car back while flying themselves. None of them had any intent to emigrate. It's relevant for travelers. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 9):

Yes they are a requirement under the Geneva Convention on Road Traffic (1949) and the Vienna Convention on Road Traffic (1968).

You can buy them on amazon for a few dollars.

The sticker you want should look like this[image: Canadian Bumper sticker]

Comment: Once the car is registered in CZ and has CZ plates you can take the sticker off, btw. It must be a pretty nice car to go through the trouble of shipping it to Prague with you.

Comment: Well, it's Mercedes AMG C63s coupe. It's quite useless in North America as I can't really drive it the way it's meant to be driven. Over in CZ the roads are twisty curvy. Prague is not far from Bavaria where I can use the 300 km/h speed limit of the car.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. If it had been an average family saloon there there wouldn't have been much point shipping it. You'll have a blast on the autobahn. Make sure you have a read of this first though.
http://www.gettingaroundgermany.info/autobahn.shtml#regs
Apparently only about 1/3 of the autobahn has no speed limit and the fines are steep if you get caught flooring it an an area with a speed limit

Comment: @zeocrash Fines in Germany for traffic violations are ridiculously low. Exceeding the speed limit by 20km/h outside built-up areas will costs you a mere 30€.

Comment: In general, you wouldn't want to drive fast in speed limit zones as it's packed with cars. Out in the open country in between major cities with less traffic it's more fun and safer as well. Once you go over 250 km/h, your major concern would be cars in the right lane. You gotta watch them so they don't get into your lane.